# Save svn properties (externals) during svn to git conversion to a file inside git repo

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I'm trying to migrate a complicated subversion repository to git with 20,000.  It has externals that change at least every 100 revisions.  It has (and sadly depends on) empty folders.

My main question is if there is a way to do the following.

As the conversion happens, for every revision, run `svn propget svn:externals -R` and put it in a file in the root of the newly created git repository.  That way it becomes possible to at least know how to recreate how they were hooked up on any given revision when checking out an older commit from before the conversion.

If there is a way to run an arbitrary command on each converted revision before it is committed, that would be enough to get me where I need to be, es (and be able to do a lot more.)

Comment: I don't think it's possible during the initial clone but possible after. Run [`git rebase --exec somescript --interactive --root branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt--xltcmdgt) for all branches and in the hypothetical `somescript` do: 1) extract `git-svn-id:` from the current commit; 2) run any command using extracted revision ID; 3) `git add . && git commit --amend` to commit new file(s).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Subgit for converting at least "some range of revisions", because [it has to create](https://subgit.com/documentation/faq.html#svn-externals) `.gitsvnextmodules` file automagically